# ON binding too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind a handler on a UL to detect when a div is clicked inside LI and then trigger a hyperlink click event within the LI.

Note: I only want clicking .col2 to trigger the event.

I am getting **too much recursion** error because the click event of the hyperlink is trigger the click event on the UL

I have tried stopPropagation but it doesnt seem to work, any ideas?

```
$('#ul_search').on('click', 'div.col2', MyClickHandler);

function MyClickHandler(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var control = $(this);
    control.find('a').click();

    e.stopPropagation();
}

<ul id="ul_search">
    <li>
        <div class="col1">
            Col1
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            Go to 
            <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
            by clicking here
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="col1">
            Col1
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            Go to
            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
            by clicking here
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

Please note:
Specifically I want to cancel the click event from the UL and trigger the click event of the HYPERLINK (as I have other page handlers that listen for hyperlink clicks) without causing the recursion.

Is this even possible?

Comment: have you tried $('#ul_search li').on('click', 'div.col2', MyClickHandler);

Comment: Have you tried `return false` at the end of your click handler?  This will stop propagation.

Comment: return false does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply ensure that the clicked element is the same element that the event handler is being called on.

```
function MyClickHandler(e) {
    if ( this == e.target ) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        $(this).find('a')[0].click(); // need to trigger the native click event, not jquery
    }
}
```

Comment: Added stopPropagation to stop the ul click event from propagating, should still properly handle the anchor click.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't propagation up from the `div`, but up from the `a`.

When the `a` is clicked, the event propagates to the `div`'s click handler, which causes another click on the `a`, which propagates up to the `div`.. etc

This might be a better solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/JJwct/

```
function MyClickHandler(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');    
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but I want to trigger the .click event without causing recursion because I have another handler on the page to monitor click events.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to stop the recursion. The jquery documentation states:

> A handler can prevent the event from bubbling further up the document
>   tree (and thus prevent handlers on those elements from running) by
>   calling event.stopPropagation(). ***Any other handlers attached on the
>   current element will run however***.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

The way I worked around the problem was change the design altogether and do away with the event handler.

I wrapped the col2 div with the hyperlink instead.

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="action"></a>
    <div class="col1">
        Col1
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <div class="col2">
          Go to Google by clicking here
      </div>
    </a>
</li>
```